# JavaScript not firing on gridview

Tags: javascript

I have some JavaScript code, which needs to run against my gridview when it loads up to the page. The gridview itself is dynamically added to the page through a user control.

To apply the script, I have written the following code, which is applied using page pre render method: `gridview1.attributes.add["onload"] = "configureGridview()";

The JavaScript function itself is on the master page. I do have other JavaScript functions on my master, and these all work but this one!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
configureGridview()
});
```

or simple pure HTML and Js

```
<body onload='configureGridview()'>
```

I highly recommend the jQuery solution since it has many benefits, like waiting for the DOM to load before running.